# Get checkbox value in jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, forms, checkbox

How can I get a checkbox's value in jQuery?

Answer (score 1368, accepted):

To check whether it is **checked or not**, do:

```
if ($('#check_id').is(":checked"))
{
  // it is checked
}
```

To get the **value** of the Value attribute you can do something like this:

```
$("input[type='checkbox']").val();
```

Or if you have set a `class` or `id` for it, you can:

```
$('#check_id').val();
$('.check_class').val();
```

However this will return the **same** value whether it is checked or not, this can be confusing as it is different to the submitted form behaviour.

Comment: If I try `$($0).val()` in Chrome, and untick the checkbox, the answer is "on" even though it is not ticked. But `$($0).is(":checked")` returns the right value.

Comment: upvoted wrong answer . realizing its indeed `on` always a bit later

Comment: Sorry, but this answer literally wasted around 1 hour of my time. All checkboxes are "on" with using `.val();` I'm strongly suggesting to use `.is(":checked")` to anyone reading this!

Comment: How about `$('#check_id').checked` ?

Answer (score 295):

Those 2 ways are working:

- `$('#checkbox').prop('checked')`
- `$('#checkbox').is(':checked')` (thanks <kbd>@mgsloan</kbd>)

```js
$('#test').click(function() {
    alert("Checkbox state (method 1) = " + $('#test').prop('checked'));
    alert("Checkbox state (method 2) = " + $('#test').is(':checked'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Check me: <input id="test" type="checkbox" />
```

Answer (score 68):

Try this small solution:

```
$("#some_id").attr("checked") ? 1 : 0;
```

or

```
$("#some_id").attr("checked") || 0;
```

Comment: Or !!($("#some_id").attr("checked"))

Comment: `attr` is deprecated. You should use `prop` instead.

Answer (score 57):

The best way of retrieving a checkbox's value is as following

```
if ( elem.checked ) 
if ( $( elem ).prop( "checked" ) ) 
if ( $( elem ).is( ":checked" ) )
```

as explained in the official documentations in jQuery's website. The other methods have nothing to do with the **value of the `checked` property** of the checkbox, they are checking the attribute. In other words, they are testing the initial state of the checkbox when the page was loaded. So in short:

- When you have the element and you know it is a checkbox you can simply read its property. You don't even need jQuery for that (i.e. `elem.checked`) or you can use `$(elem).prop("checked")` if you want to rely on jQuery.
- If you need to know (or compare with) the value when the element was first loaded (i.e. the default value) the correct way to do this, is `elem.getAttribute("checked")` or `elem.prop("defaultChecked")`.

Please note that `elem.attr("checked")` is modified only after version 1.6.1+ of jQuery to return the same result as `elem.prop("checked")`.

Some answers are misleading or imprecise, Please check below yourself:

http://api.jquery.com/prop/

Comment: `.is(":checked")` and `.prop(":checked")` are working the same for me w/ jQuery 1.10.0

Comment: @Josh, you are right thanks! I updated the answer to clarify for future readers.

Answer (score 29):

Just to clarify things:

```
$('#checkbox_ID').is(":checked")
```

Will return 'true' or 'false'

Answer (score 22):

```
$('#checkbox_id').val();
$('#checkbox_id').is(":checked");
$('#checkbox_id:checked').val();
```

Comment: does not work. you might need a column before checked ':checked'

Comment: .val() doesn't work.  Returns 'on' regardless of checked.

Comment: `$('#checkbox_id').is(":checked");` returns a boolean, exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 19):

Simple but effective and assumes you know the checkbox will be found:

```
$("#some_id")[0].checked;
```

Gives `true`/`false`

Answer (score 17):

```
//By each()
var testval = [];
 $('.hobbies_class:checked').each(function() {
   testval.push($(this).val());
 });


//by map()
var testval = $('input:checkbox:checked.hobbies_class').map(function(){
return this.value; }).get().join(",");

 //HTML Code

 <input type="checkbox" value="cricket" name="hobbies[]"  class="hobbies_class">Cricket 
  <input type="checkbox" value="hockey" name="hobbies[]" class="hobbies_class">Hockey
```

**Example**

   [Demo](http://qaify.com/blog/how-to-get-checkbox-value-in-jquery/)

Answer (score 11):

```
jQuery(".checkboxClass").click(function(){
        var selectedCountry = new Array();
        var n = jQuery(".checkboxClass:checked").length;
        if (n > 0){
            jQuery(".checkboxClass:checked").each(function(){
                selectedCountry.push($(this).val());
            });
        }
        alert(selectedCountry);
    });
```

Answer (score 7):

```
$("input[name='gender']:checked").val();
```

this worked in my case, anyone looking for a simple way, must try this syntax.
Thanks

Comment: This also worked in my case. Thanks

Answer (score 6):

Despite the fact that this question is asking for a jQuery solution, here is a pure JavaScript answer since nobody has mentioned it.

### Without jQuery:

Simply select the element and access the [`checked` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XUL/Attribute/checked) (which returns a boolean).

```js
var checkbox = document.querySelector('input[type="checkbox"]');

alert(checkbox.checked);
```

```html
<input type="checkbox"/>
```

---

Here is a quick example listening to the `change` event:

```js
var checkbox = document.querySelector('input[type="checkbox"]');
checkbox.addEventListener('change', function (e) {
    alert(this.checked);
});
```

```html
<input type="checkbox"/>
```

---

To select checked elements, use the [`:checked` pseudo class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:checked) (`input[type="checkbox"]:checked`).

Here is an example that iterates over checked `input` elements and returns a mapped array of the checked element's names.

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/auohk23f/)

```
var elements = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]:checked');
var checkedElements = Array.prototype.map.call(elements, function (el, i) {
    return el.name;
});

console.log(checkedElements);
```

```js
var elements = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]:checked');
var checkedElements = Array.prototype.map.call(elements, function (el, i) {
    return el.name;
});

console.log(checkedElements);
```

```html
<div class="parent">
    <input type="checkbox" name="name1" />
    <input type="checkbox" name="name2" />
    <input type="checkbox" name="name3" checked="checked" />
    <input type="checkbox" name="name4" checked="checked" />
    <input type="checkbox" name="name5" />
</div>
```

Comment: This is top result on Google, so this answer needs more upvotes!

Answer (score 5):

You could use the following. It is tested working OK.

```
$('#checkbox_id').is(":checked"); // jQuery
```

if `checkbox` is checked this will return `true` and vice versa.

This below code fragment is for anyone trying to do the same in JavaScript.

```
document.getElementById("checkbox_id").checked //JavaScript
```

return `true` if `checkbox` is checked

Comment: `.is(":checked");` giving true false value which is a great answer

Answer (score 3):

Here is how to get the value of **all checked checkboxes** as an array:

```
var values = (function() {
                var a = [];
                $(".checkboxes:checked").each(function() {
                    a.push(this.value);
                });
                return a;
            })()
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the following code:

```
$('input[name^=CheckBoxInput]').val();
```

Answer (score 2):

to get value of checked checkboxex in `jquery`:

```
var checks = $("input[type='checkbox']:checked"); // returns object of checkeds.

for(var i=0; i<checks.length; i++){
    console.log($(checks[i]).val()); // or do what you want
});
```

in `pure js`:

```
var checks = document.querySelectorAll("input[type='checkbox']:checked");

for(var i=0; i<checks.length; i++){
    console.log(checks[i].value); // or do what you want
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.class[value=3]').prop('checked', true);
```

Comment: The question is asking how to *get the value* not how to check something with a particular default value.

Answer (score 0):

Best way is `$('input[name="line"]:checked').val()`

And also you can get selected text `$('input[name="line"]:checked').text()`

Add value attribute and name to your radio button inputs. Make sure all inputs have same name attribute.

```
<div class="col-8 m-radio-inline">
    <label class="m-radio m-radio-filter">
        <input type="radio" name="line" value="1" checked> Value Text 1
    </label>
    <label class="m-radio m-radio-filter">
        <input type="radio" name="line" value="2"> Value Text 2
    </label>
    <label class="m-radio m-radio-filter">
        <input type="radio" name="line" value="3"> Value Text 3
    </label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

For more than 1 checkbox always use named array as show in the below example with countries, as you know countries can be selected multiple so I used name="countries[]" and while checking checkboxes you have to reference it by name as shown in below example

```js
var selectedCountries = ["Pakistan", "USA"];

$(document).ready(function () {
  $.each(selectedCountries, function (index, country) {
    $(`input[name='countries[]'][value='${country}']`).attr('checked', 'checked');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p>
  <input type="checkbox" name="countries[]" value="Pakistan">
  Pakistan
</p>
<p>
  <input type="checkbox" name="countries[]" value="India">
  India
</p>
<p>
  <input type="checkbox" name="countries[]" value="USA">
  USA
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

If only one child is expected to be selected:

```
form.querySelector(":checked").value
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.laravel').click(function(){
        var val = $(this).is(":checked");
        $('#category').submit();
    });
});
```

```
<form action="{{route('directory')}}" method="post" id="category">
                        <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
                        <input name="category" value="{{$name->id}}"  class="laravel" type="checkbox">{{$name->name}}
                      </form>
```

Answer (score -1):

Just attention, as of today, 2018, due to api changing over the years. 
removeAttr are depricated, NOT working anymore!

Jquery Check or unCheck a checkbox:

Bad, not working any more.

```
   $('#add_user_certificate_checkbox').removeAttr("checked");

   $('#add_user_certificate_checkbox').attr("checked","checked");
```

Instead you should do:

```
      $('#add_user_certificate_checkbox').prop('checked', true);
      $('#add_user_certificate_checkbox').prop('checked', false);
```