# Get value attribute of the clicked checkbox via JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have got this `checkbox` which has value **1**.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="option_1" id="checkbox_1" value="1">
```

Also I use this method to make checked/unchecked it.

```
$('input[id^="checkbox_"]').not('#checkbox_all').click(function () {
            $('#checkbox_all').prop('checked', false);

    // Get 'VALUE' of the checkbox here   

});
```

What I need is somehow get 'VALUE' of the clicked `checkbox`. So In that case it should be **1**.

Any clue how do it could be done?

Thank you!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get checkbox value in jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2834350/get-checkbox-value-in-jquery)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

In your click method use this to get the value

```
$(this).attr("value");
```

`$(this)` is referencing to the object that has been clicked.

EDIT:
you could also use `$(this).val();` but sometimes I had problems with elder versions of IE so I did recommend `$(this).attr("value")` in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

```
​<html>

​<head>

​</head>

<body>
    <input type="checkbox" name="option_1" id="checkbox_1" value="1">
</body>

​</html>​​​​​​​

$('input[id^="checkbox_"]').not('#checkbox_all').click(function () {
            $('#checkbox_all').prop('checked', false);

   alert($(this).val());  

});​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/heten/

Working :)

Answer (score 1):

I think you just need `$(this).val();` in your click event.

Also, if you need to work with that value as an int later, use

`var x = parseInt($(this).val(),10);`

Answer (score 0):

The `val` jQuery method should see you right.

```
$('#checkbox_all').val();
```

http://api.jquery.com/val/