# How to get the value of checkbox in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I have an HTML element:

```
<a style='text-decoration:none;' id='$innerdata[0]' class='cat' href='#'>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type='checkbox' name='vehicle' value='Bike'>&nbsp;$innerdata[1]</a>
```

I am trying to get the value of checkbox, but `alert()` is printing undefined.

```
$('body').on('click', '.cat', function() 
{
    $topcat = $(this);
    alert ($topcat.closest().find('[type=checkbox]').val());
}
```

How do I get the value of the checkbox?

Comment: no need for `.closest`.

Comment: `closest` needs a a selector. WHat does html look like?

Comment: Do you want the `value`, or a true/false result?

Comment: re @WeSt's comment: specifically, this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/19932511/740639A . But your question seems to be more one of a DOM traversal.

Comment: Here you'll find the answer for this questions and very others questions about jQuery selectors, with examples.
http://api.jquery.com/checkbox-selector/

Comment: Why do you have a checkbox inside an anchor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Omit the `closest`  - all you need is the `find`

```
$topcat.find(':checkbox').val();
```

Comment: checkbox in an `<a>` ?

Answer (score 0):

```
$('input[type=checkbox][name=vehicle]').val()     // general method using jQuery
```

You should add some unique `id` or `class`, otherwise selecting the right input might be tricky. See:

```
// Selects first checkbox with name `asd`
$('input[type=checkbox][name=asd]:eq(0)').val()   // jQuery
$('input[type=checkbox][name=asd]')[0].value      // jQuery + DOM
```

Comment: What if there are multiple checkboxes with that name? OP needs the one associated with the particular anchor that was clicked.

Comment: @nnnnnn You are right!