# My solution to check if the Check Box is checked not working?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, checkbox

I am trying to find if the Check Box is checked or  not. I am sure I am writing the write code but it's not working. Following is my code:

```
@Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.Country, new { id = "country" })
```

And my JavaScript Code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

  if ($("#country").is(":checked"))
  {
     alert("Working");
  }

});
```

Comment: can you check html element? is it have a checkbox that has a "country" id attribute

Comment: Not so much code so I cannot tell if the checkbox will always be unchecked when the page loads? If that is the case it won't trigger alert since the function only runs when the document has been loaded

Answer (score 0):

perhaps try jquery on `load` instead of on `document ready`:

```
$(document).on({
  load: function () {
       if ($("#country").is(":checked")){
          alert("Working");
       }
  }
});
```

Comment: I am trying `onchange` event but not working. Its not reading the id of country. I might need to use something like this: `$("input:checkbox#country")`

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the checkbox is actually checked when the document has loaded, if not the if state will return false and it runs only once.
You could always try with

```
$('#country').prop('checked')
```

Also here is another thread which provides multiple solutions [Get checkbox value in jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2834350/get-checkbox-value-in-jquery)