# Flask Jquery Post form not passing checkbox data as 0 or 1 passing 'on' value weird

Tags: jquery, json, flask

Basically I have a form that submits notes on work orders. I've got it posting but now its not passing checkbox data no matter if the box is checked it still goes thru as if its not. It passed a "on"

```
Object { result: "on" }variable.
```

my ajax code.

```
  /*global $*/
    $('#noteform').submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var csrf_token = "{{ csrf_token() }}";
        var data = {};
        var Form = this;

        $.each(this.elements, function(i, v) {
            var input = $(v);
            data[input.attr("name")] = input.val();
            delete data["undefined"];
        });

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/ticket/add/note',
            dataType: 'json',
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            data: JSON.stringify(data),
            context: Form,
            success: function(callback) {
                console.log(callback);
                $('#notes').load(' #notes');
                $('#notecount').load(' #notecount');
                $('input[type=text], textarea').val('');
                $('input[type=checkbox]').prop("checked", false);
            },
            error: function() {
                alert('error posting!');
            }
        });

        $.ajaxSetup({
                beforeSend: function(xhr, settings) {
                    if (!/^(GET|HEAD|OPTIONS|TRACE)$/i.test(settings.type) && !this.crossDomain) {
                        xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", csrf_token);
                    }
                }
        });

    });
```

Comment: Please update your post to show code and what you've tried so far so we can help you.

Comment: Just updated. Hope you can help

Comment: Check out the following post on how to get the value from a checkbox in jQuery: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2834350/get-checkbox-value-in-jquery

Comment: @SteveB , I've seen that I just honestly want to pass a 0 or 1 so I can save it to a row. It basically distinguishes if the note is private or not I dont want to create a if statement with similar outputs just to achieve 1 thing.

Comment: Is there a reason you are sending JSON-stringified manually-serialized form data, and not the more usual `var data = $(this).serialize()`?

Comment: Show how you generate the checkbox (if you do not give it a value, the its default is "on" in accordance with the standards)

Comment: You may need to do something special for checkboxes. If you check if the element is a checkbox using $('#myinput').is(':checkbox'), then you can handle the checkbox different from other elements and return the 0 or 1 you want.

Comment: @Roamer-1888 JSON.serialize is not a function

Comment: @StephenMuecke <input type="checkbox" id="private_note" name="private_note"> Regular html is how I'm calling it. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Er, correct, `JSON.serialize` is indeed not a function. I know that.

Comment: You have not given it a `value` attribute, so when you use `input.val()` it returns `"on"` (the default). But in anycase, you need to check if the `type` is a `checkbox` and the use `.is(':checked')` to check is its `checked` and based on that, return `0` or `1`

Comment: And regarding the comment by @Roamer-1888 - its `data = $('form').serialize();` which will correctly serialize all your inputs to a query string - but you need to remove the `contentType` option so it uses the default `'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'`

Comment: @StephenMuecke is there a way to separate the data instead of its being an array? Im new to this and it's only 3 being passed body, is_private, and workorderid

Comment: What do you mean _an array_ - nothing in your code is creating an array (just an object with properties representing the name/value pairs of your inputs). And I have no idea what _body, is_private, and workorderid_ are - you have not shown any of your html.