# How to get value from checkbox

Tags: jquery, checkbox

I am using a radio box with style but I am not getting its value, First I have used simple radio box which was working but I have changed its style now I am not getting its value.

```js
$("body").on('click', '.status_enable', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault(); 

    var enable = $('.status_enable').val();
    console.log(enable);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="radio red icheck">
    <label>                                                      
        <input type="radio" name="status" onclick="alert('dlfkjdkl')" value="1" class="status_enable" checked>
        Enable
    </label>
</div>
```

Comment: Where is your code? Do you get a different value, or no value at all?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get checkbox value in jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2834350/get-checkbox-value-in-jquery)

Comment: Your code works just fine.

Answer (score -1):

To get the value of your checkbox, just do `$(.status_enable).val();`

Comment: If I use without label I am getting its value but if write inside label I am not getting its value